# OSError: [WinError 126] Module not found

Tags: python, operating-system, vlc, windows64

I have a program that should play a mp.3 file from my computer via python-vlc but everytime I run it I get that error message. Does anyone know what I have to do?

```
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer("C://Users/Flo/Desktop/Python/Mambo/nevergonnagiveyouup.mp3")
player.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

your mp3 file was not found by python because of '//' replace this to '/'.

```
import vlc 
player = vlc.MediaPlayer("C:/Users/Flo/Desktop/Python/Mambo/nevergonnagiveyouup.mp3")    
player.play()
```

Comment: Python finds the mp3 file, the problem is that a dll file of some sort isnt loaded or something. When python doesnt find the file it's a different error